# requests Table Azure Application Insights which operation belongs to which resource?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor, azure-monitor-workbooks

I am using Workbook in Azure Monitor and trying to create a dashboard.

My All resources data goes into 1 Application Insights  resource.
I have resources like storage, Azure Functions, VPN, Web App etc created in this azure account.
One subscription i am using.

I am trying to run query on requests table

[image]

I want to create dashboard for a particular WebApp say namely "ABC"

OR

I want to create 1 dashboard for resources WebApp, Azure Function, Storage  say of name containing "XYZ"
requests table does not contain resourceid column. Which other Table i should use to get resource type and resource id, name

Comment: Did you inspect the values of `cloud_RoleName`, `cloud_RoleInstance` and `appName` to see if they shed any light on the resource involved? `requests | project cloud_RoleName, cloud_RoleInstance, appName`

Comment: i noticed operation_Id table is common across multiple tables. Can this be of some help?

Comment: @PeterBons will check and share update

Comment: `operation_Id` is to correlate all telemetry from a given operation (like a request). It won't help for your specific issue.

Comment: application insights itself doesn't collect resource id information, because the thing *using* appinsights doesn't need to be part of azure (you can use AI on anything that can run javascript, or anything else that supports the various sdks).  if you have resource information, you'd have to add that as custom dimensions, as shown in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I had like the same question while logging into a common app insights resource.

From what I saw, there was no common property across all the different logging applications, I could have been using to determine the telemetry-source.

What I ended up with was to add a custom property to all telemetry using a telemetry initializer (which can be added during the startup e.g. within Azure Functions, as well as AppService). For the Storage, I don't know whether this can be also done.

```cs
    // C# sample for the initializer
    public class ComponentNameTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        private readonly string _ComponentName;

        public ComponentNameTelemetryInitializer(string assemblyName)
        {
            _ComponentName = assemblyName;
        }

        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            if (telemetry is ISupportProperties propTelemetry)
            {
                propTelemetry.Properties["ComponentName"] = _ComponentName;
            }
        }
    }
```

That way I can just filter the log for the custom dimension *ComponentName* and I get all entries from a specific application.

Comment: But now data is already generated. How to resolve